# Understand a part of the proof the Schroder Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the Lemma in a book:
Let X be a set and p:℘X→℘X a function which is monotonic, in the sense that if A⊆B⊆X, then p(A)⊆p(B). Then there is a set Z⊆X such that p(Z)=Z

This is its Proof in the book:
We set Z =⋃{A⊆X:A⊆p(A)}. Take z∈Z. Then there is a set A⊆X such that z∈A and A⊆p(A). So z∈p(A). Moreover, A⊆Z,****question1**** so p(A)⊆p(Z) by hypothesis. Thus z∈p(Z). We have shown that z⊆p(Z). Again by hypothesis ****question2****, p(Z)⊆p(p(Z)). So p(Z) is one of the sets in the family whose union is Z. But this means that p(Z)⊆Z. So we have Z=p(Z), as claimed

My question 1) is why is he so sure that "Moreover, A⊆Z"?

And my question 2) is: the hypothesis says A⊆B⊆X so how is he so sure that p(Z)⊆p(p(Z)) if what he only knows is that z⊆p(Z), but he hasn't proved that p(Z)⊆X? at all if the hypothesis clearly says A⊆B⊆X ?

(This lemma has costed me a lot of time trying to understand it, it is part of the proof of schroder Bernstein theorem that says that if there is an injective function from X to Y and an injective function from Y to X then there is a bijective function from X to Y but this is the lemma that I have problems with)

Comment: (1) $A \subset Z$ since $Z$ is the union of sets one of which is $A$. 2) Similarly, $Z \subset X$ because it is the union of subsets of $X$. That's a pretty pretty proof. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: We have $A\subseteq p(A)$, and by the definition at the beginning of the proof, $Z$ is the union of all $A$ with this property. So $A\subseteq Z$.

Question 2: $p(Z)\subseteq p(p(Z))$ because $p$ is monotonic. Let $U=p(Z)$.  Then by monotonicity $U\subseteq p(U)$.

Comment: And about the question 2, what I still don't undestand is that the hypothesys says this: which is monotonic, but not just monotonic, but monotonic in the sense that if A⊆B⊆X, then p(A)⊆p(B) so one would have to prove that A⊆B⊆X, especially that p(Z)⊆X but the only thing I know about is that p:℘X→℘X and what does it have to do with p(Z)⊆X?,  I guess that  p(Z)⊆℘X but not that p(Z)⊆X, (and I'm even not sure)

Comment: @CristianMarvin: Everything is a subset of $X$. In particular $Z$ is by the definition of $Z$.